# Problems with trying to remove a file from a folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to know what is wrong with this code. It's supposed to download images and then remove them from the directory:

```
import discord
import re
import os

token = ''

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Name: {0}'.format(self.user.name))
        print('ID: {0}'.format(self.user.id))
        print('{0} Is Online'.format(self.user))

    async def on_message(self, message):
        attachmentimg = re.compile(r'(.(jpe?g|JPE?G|png|PNG))')
        attachmentgif = re.compile(r'(.(gif|GIF))')
        image = re.compile(r'https?:\/\/\S*?\/[^\/.]+\.(jpg|png)')
        if len(message.attachments) > 0 and attachmentimg.search(message.attachments[0].url) and message.channel.id == 516468839190626336:
            await message.attachments[0].save('C:/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/Images/' + message.attachments[0].filename)
            print('Downloaded: {0}'.format(message.attachments[0].filename))
            os.remove('C:/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/Images/' + message.attachments[0].filename)

client = MyClient()
client.run(token, bot=False, reconnect=True)
```

Does it remove the file from the directory before it is even added to the directory? On the console it shows that the file has been downloaded but I don't see the process of it being added and removed from the folder. I know the code is working because when I don't use os.remove I can see the file appear in the folder.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between what you want this to do and what it is doing.

Comment: It's saving images posted on a channel in a Discord server into a folder and then removing them once the image attachments are saved to a folder. It removes the file but on the console it shows that the file has been downloaded but I don't see the process of it being added and removed from the folder. What's supposed to happen is that once the image has been posted to a channel, the file is supposed to appear on the folder briefly and then disappear because of os.remove as it removes the file but none of that is happening even though on the console it shows that the file has been downloaded.

Comment: add an `await asyncio.sleep(5)` before the `os.remove`.  That should give you time to see the file before it is deleted.

Comment: Okay but it's weird because few months ago it was not like that.